# Derive formula for condition (A)

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the linear system $Ax=b$ where

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}2&4\\1&2+\varepsilon\end{bmatrix}
$$

1) Derive a formula for $\operatorname{cond}_1 ( A )$, the $1$-norm condition number of $A$.

Isn't the formula $\operatorname{cond}(a) = \|A\| \|A^{-1}\|$ or is it asking for something else?

2) What is $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0} \operatorname{cond}_1 ( A )$?

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\| A \|_1 = \max_j \sum_i a_{ij} = 6 + \epsilon$$

$$\| A^{-1} \| = \frac1{2\epsilon} (1 + \epsilon)$$

This shows that its limit is $+ \infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, and indicates that $A$ becomes more ill-conditioned as $\epsilon$ gets smaller.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, another question. What does the general graph of matrix A looks like without knowing x or b? And what is the potential effects of small perturbations in the coefficients of A?